# Adjust distance between x-axis and text in R plot

Tags: r, plot

In the plot below, you probably find the distance between x-aixs and the date (Jan-01-60 to Mar-31-16) is large.

[image: Plot of a time series data]

Is there anyway I could make the distance smaller?

Here is my example code:

```
plot(dates, data, type = "l", lwd = 3, ylab = " ", 
     xlab = " ", col = "gray35", xaxt='n', ann = FALSE)
axis(side=1, at=dates_ten, labels=format(dates_ten, "%b-%d-%y"), las =     
     1, cex.axis=0.5, las = 1, font = 2, tcl = -0.2)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `padj` argument to `axis`

```
# make a reproducible example 
dates <- seq(as.Date("2016/1/1"), as.Date("2016/4/1"), "days")
dates_ten <- seq(as.Date("2016/1/1"), as.Date("2016/4/1"), "10 days")
set.seed(42)
data <- rnorm(seq_along(dates))
```

Vary `padj` as needed:

```
plot(dates, data, type = "l", lwd = 3, ylab = " ", 
     xlab = " ", col = "gray35", xaxt='n', ann = FALSE)
axis(side=1, at=dates_ten, labels=format(dates_ten, "%b-%d-%y"), las = 1,
     cex.axis=0.5, las = 1, font = 2, tcl = -0.2, padj = -2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very helpful!